# ng-disabled in directive not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

We have a button's directive with the following template

```html
<input value="@Labels.delete" type="button" id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" ng-click="click()" 
ng-disabled="disableAction" />
```

and the code for the directive

```js
restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                title: '@',
                message: '@',
               
                delete: '&',                
                disableAction: '='
            },
```

In the form we're using it like this:

```html
<data-delete:button title="@Labels.deleteRanges"
                                    message="@String.Format(Messages.confirmDelete, String.Format(Labels.rangeX,""))"
                                    disable-action="disableAction"
                                    ng-show="sessionsSelected && weekdaysSelected"
                                    delete="deleteRanges()"></data-delete:button>
```

I added ng-show out of desperation because I can not make disabled to work correctly :( I tried disable-action = "!sessionsSelected && !weekdaysSelected" and it doesn't work. The button is always enabled.

How can I make the button conditionally disabled based on some other controller's scope properties?

Answer (score 0):

It is nice I asked because immediately after I posted I realized my own mistake in the logic conditions (not the first one I made). The correct condition which is working is:

```
disable-action="disableAction || !sessionsSelected || !weekdaysSelected"
```